# How to turn off the axis name in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, graphics

I have a question here, please take a look at the link 
[autocorrelation function](http://www.flickr.com/photos/39792648@N05/7215123162/in/photostream)
The vertical axis's name overlaped with each other, I want to turn all of them off. I call the "get(gca)", but i did not find this option. Please some one help me!

Comment: What code are you using to generate the graphs? You are probably calling `ylabel` in there somewhere to set the label? (if you did `ylabel('')` as you generate each subplot that'd clear the label)

Comment: You can also get the `ylabel` to span two lines by inserting a new line. See for example [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Inserting_Newlines_into_Plot_Labels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>See the [axes properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html), which you can change with `set()`.</strike>

```
 set(gca,'ylabel','');
```

edit: Hmm. It looks like they've changed things a bit since older versions of MATLAB and have made the xlabel/ylabel/zlabel properties an object rather than a simple text string. See the axes properties page I linked to; the new syntax is this:

```
set(get(gca, 'ylabel'),'String','');
```

Or you can use the `ylabel()` function:

```
ylabel(gca,'');
```

In case it's not obvious, you can replace any instance of `gca` with an axis handle, so if you have multiple subplots and you keep the handles for each axis, you can just use it, for example `h = plot(something, something_else); ylabel(h, '');`

Comment: Or, to do it in one go: `ylabel(findall(gcf,'type','axes'),'')`